# JavaScript Function which counts number of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to write a function which counts types of elements in the DOM

```
function setNumbers(){
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0;
    var d = 0;
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.background = 'black';
    var anchors = document.getElementById('anchors');
    var buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var events = document.getElementById('events');


    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i =0; i<elements.length; i++){      

        if (elements[i].nodeName === 'A') {
            a++;
            span.innerHTML = "anchors - " + a;      
            span.style.border = '1px solid yellow';
            span.style.color = 'yellow';
            anchors.appendChild(span);
        }
        if (elements[i].nodeName === 'TEXTAREA' || elements[i].nodeName === 'INPUT' ) {
            b++;
            span.innerHTML = "textfields - " + b;           
            span.style.border = '1px solid orange';
            span.style.color = 'orange';
            text.appendChild(span);

        }
        if (elements[i].nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
            c++;
            span.innerHTML = "buttons - " + c;          
            span.style.border = '1px solid green';
            span.style.color = 'green';
            buttons.appendChild(span);

        }
        if (elements[i].onclick) {
            d++;
            span.innerHTML = "events - " + d;           
            span.style.border = '1px solid pink';
            span.style.color = 'pink';
            events.appendChild(span);

        }
    }
}
setNumbers();
```

Here is the code. The function has to append the number of elements in relevant div, but appends only textarea elements. Can you please check my function and tell where I missed something? Thanks 
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acguvd4f/7/)

Comment: You're overwriting `span.innerHTML` everywhere, so how do you expect to see anything but the data of the last encountered element?

Comment: Yes, you're right, silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same `span` variable across the scope, so it is override everytime. The last element in your HTML matching `if` is textarea, so it is the last type being counted.

Shortest fix: remove `span` and use this instead:

```
    if (elements[i].nodeName === 'A') {
        a++;
        anchors.innerHTML = "anchors - " + a;       
        anchors.style.border = '1px solid yellow';
        anchors.style.color = 'yellow';
    }
```

PS: better idea would be to create a function counting elements of a specified kind (eg. `setNumbers(type)`), now you repeat yourself many times and use global selector `*` choosing all the items, even though you need only these matching a, textarea etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes, repeat of the code is another issue, going to improve it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/acguvd4f/8/

**JS:-**

```
function setNumbers(){
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0;
    var d = 0;

    var anchors = document.getElementById('anchors');
    var buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var events = document.getElementById('events');


    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i =0; i<elements.length; i++){      
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.background = 'black';
        if (elements[i].nodeName === 'A') {
            a++;
            span.innerHTML = "anchors - " + a;      
            span.style.border = '1px solid yellow';
            span.style.color = 'yellow';
            anchors.appendChild(span);
        }
        if (elements[i].nodeName === 'TEXTAREA' || elements[i].nodeName === 'INPUT' ) {
            b++;
            span.innerHTML = "textfields - " + b;           
            span.style.border = '1px solid orange';
            span.style.color = 'orange';
            text.appendChild(span);

        }
        if (elements[i].nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
            c++;
            span.innerHTML = "buttons - " + c;          
            span.style.border = '1px solid green';
            span.style.color = 'green';
            buttons.appendChild(span);

        }
        if (elements[i].onclick) {
            d++;
            span.innerHTML = "events - " + d;           
            span.style.border = '1px solid pink';
            span.style.color = 'pink';
            events.appendChild(span);

        }
    }
}
setNumbers();
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem was, how you solved it and what you changed in the code.

Comment: @Bergi Added the span create element inside for loop so as to fix this. Since it was the same variable(Global) everytime.